# Creating a folder on registration

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla3.0, joomla1.7

how would it be possible to create on every registration in Joomla a customized folder for every user in the images-folder? The userid should be the foldername...(images/USERID)

Where could I change the code and what should I insert?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should use a plugin that uses the onUserAfterSave event (and just check if it is a new user or even better if the folder exists).

Comment: You could check the replies to your post in the Joomla forums, where an answer was given hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a Profile Plugin for this task,

and use the `onUserAfterSave` for the folder creation section.
the basic profile plugin documentation can be found [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin).

Another option is just edit the core file, but its not recommended bcoz due to Joomla update it may lost.

If you plan to edit core file just check your model file inside `components/com_users/models/registration.php` and task `register()` in this function a send mail code is there just add your custom codes before that.

Hope its helps..